# Docker - Configuring a Datasource in a Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I have deployed a web application that runs in an Apache Tomcat server which uses a database into a container. I want to run the container by using CLI as:

docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 -e ENV_VAR='XYZ'

The context.xml looks like this:

```
<Context>
  <Resource
    name="jdbc/MYDB"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    auth="Container"
    username="user"
    password="password"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url=${db} >
  </Resource>
</Context>
```

When the container is started by run command following error msg is received:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL '${db}'
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2186)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2066)
```

Hence I can't establish the connection to the database because the environment variables exposed by Docker are not recognized at the Tomcat environment.
Is there a way to make these environment variables exposed by Docker visible to the Apache Tomcat environment?

Answer (score 1):

context.xml variables can be substituted by using CATALINA_OPTS. Prepend each variable with "-D". In your case this should be like `docker run -e "CATALINA_OPTS='-Ddb=sss'"`.

Comment: Also ran into troubles while setting multiple catalina opts - it didn't consider space character as a separator. The solution was to get rid of `'` signs: `docker run -e "CATALINA_OPTS=-Dp1=v1 -Dp2=v2"`.